# The Talos Principle Soundtrack

Tags: game-music-identification, the-talos-principle

There are a few places on YouTube where you can listen to the soundtrack to *The Talos Principle*, as well as being available on Spotify. However, there is one piece of music that I can't find anywhere: the theme played when you stand in the doorway to eternity in World C, that carries through when you actually step into it. It is also played when you reach 'heaven' after ascending the tower. The piece of music can be heard in [this clip](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2U_2IX2x4BI) from 0:13 to 0:52, anyone who has played through the game will be familiar with it.

I've trawled through the soundtrack and it isn't anywhere; is it an outside piece of music? **Can anyone help me identify the name of this track?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the game installed, there is a file *00_All.gro* in the game folder at *[path-to-game]/TheTalosPrinciple/Content/Talos*.  It is a ZIP file (I could open it using 7-Zip). In it, the music you are referring to is at *Content/Talos/Music/Cutscenes*.

It is just called **Heaven.ogg**.  I could not find any metadata in the file, so there is no more information than the file name.

Comment: Brilliant find, thank you so much! I guess since it seems to be classed as cutscene music is the reason why it hasn't made its way onto the soundtrack.